# Boolean Difference doesn't create inset faces

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I have problem with Boolean difference modifier in blender 3.6.
I am trying to make inset shapes in my model.
[image]

However after applying applying modifier with these settings

[image]

Boolean doesn't create inset faces, only holes in my model.
[image]

I never had this kind of problem with blender before. So maybe anyone had similar problem and knows how to figure it out. Thank you

Comment: Try _Solver_ > _Fast_. If that doesn't work, make sure all objects have the normals facing in the correct direction.

Comment: Thank, you Solver > Fast solved the issue